# Convert SQL Join to HQL Join: Multiple joins, one table, not joining on pk

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have searched SO, but haven't found a good exemplar for this. I have the following SQL statement that works just fine:

```
select CatA.* 
FROM TestContentElementCETPropertyValue as CatA 
  JOIN TestContentElementCETPropertyValue as CatB 
    ON CatA.testcontentelementid = CatB.testcontentelementid 
  JOIN TestContentElementCETPropertyValue as CatC
    ON CatB.testcontentelementid = CatC.testcontentelementid 
WHERE  CatA.contentelementtypepropertyid = 141 
  AND CatB.contentelementtypepropertyid = 4903   
  AND CatC.contentelementtypepropertyid = 4990
```

UPDATE: To be clear, neither the ON field or the WHERE field are the PK.

As a neophyte with HQL I'm struggling to get my head around how to write this once the "ON" clause is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The join is implicit.

```
String queryString="        select CatA FROM "   +
    "TestContentElementCETPropertyValue as CatA, "+
    "TestContentElementCETPropertyValue as CatB, "+
    "TestContentElementCETPropertyValue as CatC "+
    "WHERE  CatA.contentElementTypeProperty.id = 141 "+
    "AND CatB.contentElementTypeProperty.id= 4903   "+
    "AND CatC.contentElementTypeProperty.id = 4990  "+
    "AND CatA.testContentElement.id = CatB.testContentElement.id "+
    "AND CatB.testContentElement.id = CatC.testContentElement.id ";
```